# Produce Elasticsearch query output based on field value match, sequence and limited time frame

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, querydsl

How do I search an index for two different message texts and then only filter out the two messages that happened in the same second?

f.ex. message: "first message" and message: "second message"
(only display index entries containing first message followed by entry with second message, if the log entries occurred within 1sec of one another).

**Acceptable output:**

2020-12-18T20:26:58.089Z [INF]:First message

2020-12-18T20:26:58.184Z [ERR]:Second message

**Not acceptable output:**

(too much time between index entry 1 and index entry 2 greater than 1s)

2020-12-18T20:26:58.089Z [INF]:First message

2020-12-18T20:26:59.184Z [ERR]:Second message

(wrong sequence of events)

2020-12-18T20:26:58.184Z [ERR]:Second message

2020-12-18T20:26:59.089Z [INF]:First message

What would the query look like that produces a result set containing all matching pairs of events that happened within 1sec of each other?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is not a relational database, it is a search engine first, and a document store second. what you are requesting to do is akin to a self-join in SQL.

there is no easy way to do it, but i believe you can achieve your desired result by first running a Histogram aggregation over the entire index using 1 second interval, which would give you groups of documents that have the same "1-second" timeframe, and loop over the groups, running a separate query for each group and scanning the results for your 2 documents. this can be done fairly easily in Java, but i don't suppose you can do that easily with just ES queries.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will keep looking. I was wondering if nested queries could accomplish precisely what you are suggesting.